# Consequences of unlawful deletion of records

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, punishment, governmental-liability

The Secret Service recently admitted to the unauthorized ([according to the National Archives](https://www.archives.gov/files/records-mgmt/resources/ud-2022-0054-dhs-usss-open.pdf)) deleting of text messages relevant to the US House's investigations of events surround the January 6, 2021 insurrection.

What are the legal ramifications and consequences for this illegal activity? (for both the agency, and for individuals responsible within the agency)

Comment: I don't think that the unauthorized deletions are automatically illegal. The text messages were deleted well before any investigations into the 1/6 incident started.

Comment: @doneal24 I'm pretty sure that notion is contested

Answer (score 2):

### Up to 1 year in prison or a fine

The relevant law is [18 U.S. Code § 641 - Public money, property or records](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/641) and the value of the lost items is less than $1,000.

Comment: Damn that's nothing. Crazy.

Comment: Well, it says that it's 1 year if the value is below 1 grand, up to 10 years if the value is above that. Now the question is "what is the value of those messages?" Is it the literal cost of sending them or should they be evaluated by their contents? Is the original US costitution worth its weight in paper & ink or does it have a huge historical value?

Comment: @GACy20 the law says how you define value. The value of an SMS is its market value - essentially $0.

Comment: @DaleM Is it?  Jack Dorsey's first tweet has been sold twice, once for a very ridiculous sum, and again for a much smaller but still, objectively speaking, ridiculous sum. Might not there be strong market interest in the SMS contents?  People thinking there's the smoking gun of a conspiracy that'll save the country upon reveal might be willing to pay a hefty sum to acquire it (if they have the money). Or those trying to cover it up and get ahead of the narrative at the other extreme, etc. I kind of assume those aren't accounted for, but where's that in the laws/precedents?

Comment: @DaleM I don't think so. The law says "The word “value” means face, par, or market value, or cost price, either wholesale or retail, whichever is greater." Which means all and nothing. I'm pretty sure the market value of condemning SMSs for the US president is at least in the hundreds of thousands, but more probably millions of dollars.

Comment: I think you would also have to show that the text messages are government records. The definition is well defined and these SMS messages may not qualify.

Comment: Any idea how qualified (and/or absolute) immunity might factor into whether decision makers can be held accountable?